# java.util.Date returning different dates in JDK 5 and JDK 6

Tags: java, date, time, timezone

The below code when run with JDK5(1.5.0_09) prints

```
Fri May 03 00:00:00 GMT 3912 
5/3/12 5:30 AM
```

and when run with JDK6(1.6.0_23) prints

```
Fri May 03 00:00:00 IST 3912
5/3/12 12:00 AM
```

Obviously the difference is because of the timezone used then the Date object is created. But doesn't this cause problems for existing code when the JDK is upgraded? Is this behavior documented somewhere or am I missing something?

```
    class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date d = new Date(2012, 04, 3);
        Locale l = new Locale("en", "US","");   
        DateFormat df= DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,  DateFormat.SHORT, l );
        TimeZone t = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
        df.setTimeZone(t);      
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(df.format(d));

    }
}
```

Comment: When you start off by calling a *deprecated* constructor, you shouldn't alarm SO about inconsistent results. Yes, it causes problems and that's why it's deprecated.

Comment: Using a deprecated method is itself not really a good explanation for observing different behaviour between Java versions. In this case, the Date constructor does exactly the same in both cases, the difference is in the non-deprecated TimeZone.getTimeZone method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strange year `3192` is arising because that **deprecated** `Date` constructor assumes you are using a 2-digit year with `0` meaning `1900`.  It adds `1900` to the year number.

The difference in the timezones is not the fault of the `Date` constructor.  Your code is using `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")` to get the timezone.  That method is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) as returning the GMT timezone if it doesn't recognize the timezone string.  It would appear that Sun ADDED support for more timezones in Java 1.6.  (Most people would view this as a good thing rather than as a portability concern.)

I haven't tried it, but the following should be sufficient to insulate yourself against using GMT when your requested zone id is unrecognised.

```
    public TimeZone getZone(String id) {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone();
        if (!tz.getID().equals(id)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unrecognized zone " + id);
        }
        return tz;
    }
```

In summary, your code is broken in two respects:

- It is using a deprecated constructor.
- It is *assuming* that `getTimeZone` will understand all of your timezone Strings, and this is clearly not the case for Java 1.5.