# Is there any difference on JDK5/JDK 6 when converting String to Date

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Could it possible that JDK 5 can produce

```
"default message [Failed to convert property value of type 
'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 
'orderDate'; nested exception is  org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException:Failed to convert
from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Date for value 'Mon May 27 12:27:20 ART 2013'"
```

But not on JDK6? current application is Spring on JBoss so that the conversion is not explicit. I get this issue from Jboss server on one machine but not from other Jboss on another machine. However right now somehow I can not check the JVM detail with the server has the issue.

Comment: Maybe `ART` is a new TimeZone that one machine is not aware of?

Comment: Maybe it's not new, but it sounds like TimeZone strings can be very machine dependent... Here's [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1707799/778118) that has some discussion.

Comment: Here's another one, that says that the `Date` class has significant changes from JDK5 to JDK6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481122/java-util-date-returning-different-dates-in-jdk-5-and-jdk-6

Comment: Thanks everyone, it seems a platform issue. Current testing server is in US on windows, but remote testing server is in Argentina on Linux...so generally how to get a solution to these complicated situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt JDK Date functions has significant change from version 5 to 6. Maybe it's locale differences between two environments.

Also if you're on Spring MVC it's better practice to define a date string format, and register a property editor for it on your controller, so you can always parse/format regardless of locales, eg:

```
@InitBinder
public void registerDateBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what if we want the data format customizable from external properties file, is above solution still doable?

Comment: definitely, instead of hardcoding `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, place it an a system property / config file and pull it when registering the date binder

Comment: I get an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'e' after with customize pattern. But there is no such 'e' from custominze pattern(default_date_format=MMM/dd/yyyy), so what's going on there? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I think that exceptions arise when you tried to parse input that doesn't conform to the date format.

Comment: in current controller we have more than one data format on the UI, so what is the solution to have different binder to each method ?

Comment: I would normalize all the date data first so they all have uniform format. This might be hard and painful but better to avoid future complexity